# Hive insert query like SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am new to hive, and want to know if there is anyway to insert data into Hive table like we do in SQL. I want to insert my data into hive like

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (value1,value2..)
```

I have read that you can load the data from a file to hive table or you can import data from one table to hive table but is there any way to append the data as in SQL?

Comment: ACID properties are supported in hive post 0.14 version.So yes insert ,update delete is possible but for single row and single condition operations.https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Some of the answers here are out of date as of Hive 0.14

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL

It is now possible to insert using syntax such as:

```
CREATE TABLE students (name VARCHAR(64), age INT, gpa DECIMAL(3, 2));

INSERT INTO TABLE students
  VALUES ('fred flintstone', 35, 1.28), ('barney rubble', 32, 2.32);
```

Comment: FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:28 cannot recognize input near 'VARCHAR' '(' '64' in column type

Answer (score 23):

You can use the table generating function `stack` to insert literal values into a table.

First you need a dummy table which contains only one line. You can generate it with the help of limit.

```
CREATE TABLE one AS
SELECT 1 AS one
FROM any_table_in_your_database
LIMIT 1;
```

Now you can create a new table with literal values like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT stack(3
  , "row1", 1
  , "row2", 2
  , "row3", 3
) AS (column1, column2)
FROM one
;
```

The first argument of `stack` is the number of rows you are generating.

You can also add values to an existing table:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE my_table
SELECT stack(2
  , "row4", 1
  , "row5", 2
) AS (column1, column2)
FROM one
;
```

Answer (score 16):

Slightly better version of the unique2 suggestion is below:

```
insert overwrite table target_table
select * from 
(
select stack(
    3,                 # generating new table with 3 records
    'John', 80,        # record_1
    'Bill', 61         # record_2
    'Martha', 101      # record_3
    ) 
) s;
```

Which does not require the hack with using an already exiting table.

Comment: Why do you need to add an select statement on the outside of select stack, is that necessary?

Answer (score 8):

You can use below approach. With this, You don't need to create temp table OR txt/csv file for further select and load respectively.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tablename SELECT value1,value2 FROM tempTable_with_atleast_one_records LIMIT 1.
```

Where ***tempTable_with_atleast_one_records*** is any table with atleast one record.

But problem with this approach is that If you have INSERT statement which inserts multiple rows like below one.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable values (1 , 'value1') , (2 , 'value2') , (3 , 'value3') ;
```

Then, You need to have separate INSERT hive statement for each rows. See below.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE yourTable SELECT 1 , 'value1' FROM tempTable_with_atleast_one_records LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO TABLE yourTable SELECT 2 , 'value2' FROM tempTable_with_atleast_one_records LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO TABLE yourTable SELECT 3 , 'value3' FROM tempTable_with_atleast_one_records LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

No. This `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (x,y,z)` syntax is currently not supported in Hive.

Comment: is there a way around so that I can append data in my table as we do in SQL.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT ...` is supported, so you could put the new data in a temporary table and then insert by selecting from there.

Comment: I want to append data in hive through java client, will it work if I create a temporary data table in java and write an insert and select query in my java client only?

Comment: If you're using Java, why not append to the file in HDFS directly? Hive is not really suitable for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 6):

You could definitely append data into an existing table. (But it is actually not an append at the HDFS level). It's just that whenever you do a LOAD or INSERT operation on an existing Hive table without `OVERWRITE` clause the new data will be put without replacing the old data. A new file will be created for this newly inserted data inside the directory corresponding to that table. For example :

I have a file named demo.txt which has 2 lines :

```
ABC
XYZ
```

Create a table and load this file into it

```
hive> create table demo(foo string);
hive> load data inpath '/demo.txt' into table demo;
```

Now,if I do a SELECT on this table it'll give me :

```
hive> select * from demo;                        
OK    
ABC    
XYZ
```

Suppose, I have one more file named demo2.txt which has :

```
PQR
```

And I do a LOAD again on this table without using overwrite,

```
hive> load data inpath '/demo2.txt' into table demo;
```

Now, if I do a SELECT now, it'll give me,

```
hive> select * from demo;                       
OK
ABC
XYZ
PQR
```

HTH

Answer (score 6):

Ways to insert data into Hive table:
*for demonstration, I am using table name as **table1** and **table2***

1. `create table table2 as select * from table1 where 1=1;`
   or
   `create table table2 as select * from table1;`
2. `insert overwrite table table2 select * from table1;`
   --it will insert data from one to another. Note: It will refresh the target.
3. `insert into table table2 select * from table1;`
   --it will insert data from one to another. Note: It will append into the target.
4. `load data local inpath 'local_path' overwrite into table table1;`
   --it will load data from local into the target table and also refresh the target table.
5. `load data inpath 'hdfs_path' overwrite into table table1;`
   --it will load data from hdfs location iand also refresh the target table.
   or

   create table table2(
   col1 string,
   col2 string,
   col3 string)
   row format delimited fields terminated by ','
   location 'hdfs_location';
6. `load data local inpath 'local_path'  into table table1;`
   --it will load data from local and also append into the target table.
7. `load data inpath 'hdfs_path'  into table table1;`
   --it will load data from hdfs location and also append into the target table.
8. `insert into table2 values('aa','bb','cc');`
   --Lets say table2 have 3 columns only.
9. Multiple insertion into hive table

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can insert but not as similar to SQL.

In SQL we can insert the row level data, but here you can insert by fields (columns).

During this you have to make sure target table and the query should have same datatype and same number of columns.

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE test(stu_name STRING,stu_id INT,stu_marks INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test SELECT lang_name, lang_id, lang_legacy_id FROM export_table;
```

Answer (score 3):

To insert entire data of `table2` in `table1`. Below is a query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do insert into to insert single record. It's not supported by Hive. You may place all new records that you want to insert in a file and load that file into a temp table in Hive. Then using insert overwrite..select command insert those rows into a new partition of your main Hive table. The constraint here is your main table will have to be pre partitioned. If you don't use partition then your whole table will be replaced with these new records.

Comment: Not entirely correct. "INSERT INTO will append to the table or partition keeping the existing data in tact. (Note: INSERT INTO syntax is only available starting in version 0.8)" https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following command to insert data into the testlog table with some condition:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE testlog SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE some condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in such scenarios you should be using HBASE which facilitates such kind of insertion but it does not provide any SQL kind of query language. You need you use Java API of HBASE like the put method to do such kind of insertion. Moreover HBASE is column oriented no-sql database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use Insert query in Hive.

```
hive> create table test (id int, name string);
```

**INSERT**: INSERT...VALUES is available starting in version 0.14.

```
hive> insert into table test values (1,'mytest');
```

This is going to work for `insert`. We have to use `values` keyword.

**Note:** User cannot insert data into a complex datatype column (array, map, struct, union) using the `INSERT INTO...VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You still can insert into complex type in Hive - it works
(id is int, colleagues array)

insert into emp (id,colleagues) select 11, array('Alex','Jian') from (select '1')

Answer (score 0):

you can add values to specific columns as well, just specify the column names in which you like to add corresponding values:

```
Insert into Table (Col1, Col2, Col4,col5,Col7) Values ('Va11','Va2','Val4','Val5','Val7');
```

Make sure the columns you skip dont have not null value type.

Answer (score 0):

There are few properties to set to make a Hive table support ACID properties and to insert the values into tables as like in  SQL .

Conditions to create a ACID table in Hive.

1. The table should be stored as ORC file. Only ORC format can support ACID prpoperties for now.
2. The table must be bucketed

Properties to set to create ACID table:

```
set hive.support.concurrency =true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing =true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode =nonstrict
set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads= 1;
set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
```

set the property hive.in.test to true in hive.site.xml

After setting all these properties , the table should be created with  tblproperty 'transactional' ='true'. The table should be bucketed and saved as orc

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1 int,col2 string, col3 int) CLUSTERED BY col1 INTO 4 

BUCKETS STORED AS orc tblproperties('transactional' ='true');
```

Now its possible to inserte values into the table like SQL query.

`INSERT INTO TABLE table_name VALUES (1,'a',100),(2,'b',200),(3,'c',300);`