# How do I create a hive table without any intermediate files?

Tags: sql, hive

I want to create and populate a hive table without loading anything from disk.

Specifically, I have

```
set idlist = (1,2,3);
set values = (2,3,5);
```

I want to create a table with 9 rows:

```
id value
1  2
1  3
1  5
2  2
2  3
2  5
3  2
3  3
3  5
```

Again, I do *not* want to write a `csv` file and load it into hive.

Use cases:

1. iteration
2. creating small test samples for SO questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table my_table(id int, value int);

insert overwrite table my_table
select a.id as id, b.value as value from (
  select count(*) from my_table
) t
lateral view explode(array(1,2,3)) a as id
lateral view explode(array(2,3,5)) b as value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Hive insert query like SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425492/hive-insert-query-like-sql):

```
drop table if exists tmp__one;
create table tmp__one as select 1 as one
from <an_already_existing_non_empty_table> limit 1;

drop table if exists tmp__ids;
create table tmp__ids as select stack(3,1,2,3) as id 
from tmp__one;

drop table if exists tmp__vals;
create table tmp__vals as select stack(3,2,3,5) as val
from tmp__one;

drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table as select id, val
from tmp__ids cross join tmp__vals;

select * from my_table;

drop table tmp__one;
drop table tmp__ids;
drop table tmp__vals;
```

Alas, strictly speaking, this requires `<an_already_existing_non_empty_table>`...