# How do I cross-join a table with a list?

Tags: sql, join, hive

If I have a table `mytable` and a list

```
set vals = (1,2,3,4);
```

and I want to cross-join the table with the list (getting a new table which has 4 time as many rows as the original table and an extra `val` column), do I have a better option than creating [an explicit temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413217/how-do-i-create-a-hive-table-without-any-intermediate-files)?

What I can do is:

```
select a.*, b.val
from mytable a cross join
(select stack(4,1,2,3,4) as (val) from 
 (select * from mytable limit 1) z) b;
```

EDIT: My main use case would be passing `-hiveconf vals='4,1,2,3,4'` to `hive` and replacing `stack(4,1,2,3,4)` with `stack(${hiveconf:vals})` in the above code.

Comment: Can't you use Union? like (select 1 as stg union select 2 union select 3 union selec 4)?

Comment: @PeterRing: I think `union` would be even worse than what I have, but please do post an answer using it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.val
from a lateral view explode(array(1,2,3,4)) b as val;
```

Answer (score 5):

I dont know this will help.

```
SELECT *
from mytable cross join
(select 1 as p
union 
select 2 
union 
select 3
union 
select 4) as x
```

Comment: +1, but what if I have 20 instead of 4 values? I think your code explodes in size.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.*, b.val
from mytable a cross join
(values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5))b(val);
```