# How to insert direct values into a hive table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, insert, hive

I am new to hive. I just wanted to know how I can insert data into Hive table directly

```
Create table t1 ( name string)

and I want to insert a value eg name = 'John'
```

But I have seen so many documentation there isn't any example that inserts data directly into the table. Either I need to create a file internal or externally and add the value 'John' and load this data into the table or i can load data from another table.

My goal is to add data directly into the hive table by providing a values directly? I have provided an oracle example of a sql query I want to achieve:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (name)
values ('John')
```

I want an equivalent statement as above in Hive ?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413217/how-do-i-create-a-hive-table-without-any-intermediate-files)

Answer (score 5):

You can use hive's table generating functions,like exlode() or stack()

## Example

Table struct as (name String, age Int)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE target_table
SELECT STACK(
    2,                 # Amount of record
    'John', 80,        # record 1
    'Bill', 61         # record 2
    ) 
FROM dual              # Any table already exists
LIMIT 2;               # Amount of record! Have to add this line!
```

That will add 2 records in your target_table.

Answer (score 2):

As of latest version of Hive, `insert into .. values (...)`is not supported. The enhancement to insert/update/delete syntax is under development. Please look at the [Implement insert, update, and delete in Hive with full ACID support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5317)

Answer (score 2):

Inserting values into a table is now supported by HIVE from the version  Hive 0.14.

`CREATE TABLE students (name VARCHAR(64), age INT, gpa DECIMAL(3, 2))  CLUSTERED BY (age) INTO 2 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC;`

`INSERT INTO TABLE students VALUES ('fred flintstone', 35, 1.28), ('barney rubble', 32, 2.32);`

More can be found at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL

Comment: It should be noted, that unless the transactional feature is being used, or the VALUES array is very large, this is usually an anti-pattern, since each insert generates at least one new file in HDFS. Queries over thousands of files are very inefficient.