# Hive split a string and insert into table

Tags: hive

Here my question. I have a long string in a table, now I want to split it, and insert the result from splitting into another table.

for example.

```
INSERT TABLE table1 
SELECT 
    split(result, ';')[0],
    split(result, ';')[1],
    ...
FROM table2
WHERE ...
```

suppose result is a long string delimited by ';'

My query is not right, How can I fix it?

Comment: Try This ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053567/inserting-data-into-hive-table
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see is the first line. Alter it like so..

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1
...
```